# SQL: Select count of accomplished invoices with all items checked

Tags: sql, count, distinct

My customers submit invoices with some items in each one. I want to calculate number of accomplished invoices (which all items are checked by operator)

sample data:

```
invoiceNumber    |     ItemNumber    |     Status
a                      1                    Null
a                      2                    checked
a                      3                    Null
b                      1                    checked
b                      5                    checked
```

In sample data above, the number of finished invoice is 1 because all items in invoice number **"B"** are checked and number of unfinished invoices is 1 because in invoice **"A"**, only 1 item is checked.

My try:

```
select count(distinct invoiceNumber) as total 
from invoices 
where status is not null
```

Returns 2! I should not count row number 2 because 1 and 3 are still Null.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Specify the expected result (use same format as the table data.)

Comment: The expected result is not a recordset.  im looking for "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below query..

```
SELECT count(distinct invoiceNumber) as total
    FROM from invoices
        WHERE invoiceNumber    NOT IN (SELECT invoiceNumber
    FROM  invoices  WHERE status IS null)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `distinct` is the problem as you count the unique appearances of the `invoiceNumber` as the result. As there are two `b`s checked and one `a`, the count is 2

Try using the `select count (*)` instead or some unique id of the invoice (if there is one).

Edit:
I have misread your question. To count only the invoices that have all the rows with the status checked, you can use the `group by` and `having`.

Something similar to:

```
select count(distinct invoiceNumber) as total 
from invoices 
group by invoiceNumber, status 
having status is not null
```

Comment: This will still include invoicenumber `a` in the result

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude all invoices that have a `NULL` status for the same invoicenumber:

```
select count(distinct i1.invoicenumber)
from invoices i1
where not exists (select *
                  from invoices i2
                  where i2.invoicenumber = i1.invoicenumber
                  and i2.status is null);
```

Another option is to use `except` to remove those that have a null status:

```
select count(*)
from (
  select invoicenumber
  from invoices
  except
  select invoicenumber
  from invoices
  where status is null
);
```